# Could not find or access xxx.xxx.j2 on ansible role

Tags: ansible

I'm tyring to create a role which perform the installation of Apache2 (http). I have the following structure (where `instalar.yaml` contains the task that i'm running):

```
.
├── instalar.yml
└── roles
    └── httpd
        ├── files
        │   └── httpd.conf
        ├── handlers
        │   └── main.yml
        ├── tasks
        │   └── main.yaml
        └── templates
            └── index.html.j2
```

My `instalar.yaml` contains:

```yaml
---
- name: Playbook ejemplo roles
  hosts: aws_cev
  become: true
  roles:
    - httpd
```

And `roles/httpd/tasks/main.yaml`:

```yaml
---
- name: Install apache packages 
  yum:
    name: httpd
    state: present

- name: ensure httpd is running
  service:
    name: httpd 
    state: started

- name: Copiar el fichero de configuracion
  copy:
    src: httpd.conf 
    dest: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

#
# FAILING TASK
#
- name: Index copy
  copy:
    src: index.html.j2
    dest: /var/www/html/index.html
```

All the task runs ok except *Index copy*. This task return an error:

```
fatal: [frontal_web]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "dest": "/var/www/html/index.html",
        "module_args": {
            "dest": "/var/www/html/index.html",
            "src": "index.html.j2"
        },
        "src": "index.html.j2"
    },
    "msg": "Could not find or access 'index.html.j2'\nSearched in:
```

The error includes a list of directories where it have found such a `/roles/httpd/files`, `/roles/httpd/tasks/files/` but not the directory where I put the template (following the [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#role-directory-structure) which is `roles/httpd/templates`.

Where is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the mistake.

I was using the [copy module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html) instead of [template module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html):

```yaml
- name: Index copy
  template:
    src: index.html.j2
    dest: /var/www/html/index.html
```